# How to multiply a fixed weight matrix to a keras layer output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, multiplication

I encounter a problem when I intended to multiply a keras output with a constant tensor?
here is my code

```html
a = tf.constant(ws, "float32")
output4 = AveragePooling3D(pool_size=(X_shape[0], 1, 1), strides = None, padding='valid')(output3)
output5 = Conv3D(filters=X_shape[3], kernel_size=(1, 1, 1),padding='same',data_format='channels_last')(output4)
output6 = Lambda( tf.multiply(output5, a))(output5)
```

here is my error"

> ValueError: Tensor("Const:0", shape=(1, 1, 21, 27, 3), dtype=float32) must be from the same graph as Tensor("conv3d_1/add:0", shape=(None, 1, 21, 27, 3), dtype=float32).

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I finally found a solution for that.  model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x * ws))

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the functional API, the constant tensor needs to be provided either as an input to the model, or to a the constructor of an object inheriting for `Layer`.

Method 1 (preferred) - As an input to a custom layer:

```
class ConstMul(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, const_val, *args, **kwargs):
        ....
        self.const = const_val

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        return inputs * self.const

....
output6 = ConstMul(ws)(output5)
```

Method 2 - As a separate Input Layer:

```
const_inp = Input(shape)
....
output6 = tf.multiply(output5, const_inp)
```

Then add `const_inp` to the list of inputs to the model. This is not the best way though.

Comment: Hi Susmit, thanks a lot for your fast reply. I am a Keras newbie.:-) I have tried your method but another error  occurred. "AttributeError: 'ConstMul' object has no attribute '_expects_mask_arg'". Any idea?

Comment: I have found a solution using lamda. Thanks a lot, Susmit. Using model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x * ws))